# Java Encryption with AES-RSA works in Eclipse but not in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encryption, base64

This is probably the most weird thing that has happened to me. **The code runs perfectly in Eclipse** but **if i try to use it in Android Studio, it fail.**
After 2 days, I'm thinking it could be something related with the Commons-Codec library but at this point, and after searched everywhere on the internet, i cant find a solution to my problem. I literally didn't sleep last night trying to find a solution.

Here is my code, i pasted only what i think is relevant but if you need the entire code, let me know.

This is at server side, running on Ubuntu server.

```
 private String cifrarClaveAES(String clavepub) throws Exception{


                    byte[] sigBytes2 =  new Base64().decode(clavepub);

                    X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes2);
                    KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                    PublicKey pubKey2 = keyFact.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

                     try {
                            Cipher rsa;
                            rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
                            rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey2);



                            byte[] array = rsa.doFinal(miclaveAES.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                            String prueba = new String(new Base64().encode(array), "UTF-8");

                            return prueba;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e.toString());
                        }
                        return null;
                } 
             private  String desencriptar(String criptograma, SecretKey clave){
                    try{
                    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, clave);
                    byte[] decVal = new Base64().decode(criptograma.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                    byte[] mensaje = c.doFinal(decVal);
                    return new String(mensaje, "UTF-8");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Error al desencriptar");
                        return null;
                    }


                }
```

This is running at client side (Android APP)

private String clavePublicaToString(){ //PublicKeyToString

```
    PublicKey miclaveRSA =  claveRSA.getPublic();
    byte[] array = miclaveRSA.getEncoded();
    String clavePublica = "";


    try {
        clavePublica = new String(new Base64().encode(array), "UTF-8");



    System.out.println(clavePublica);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return clavePublica;
}
public String descifrarclaveAEScifrada(String mstring)  {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    try {
        buffer = mstring.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, claveRSA.getPrivate());
        byte[] utf8;
        byte[] depaso = new Base64().decode(buffer);

        utf8 = rsa.doFinal(depaso);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public String encriptarAES(String mensaje, SecretKey clave){

    Cipher c = null;
    byte[] criptograma = null;
    try {
            c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, clave);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(mensaje.getBytes("UTF-8"));


         criptograma = new Base64().encode(encVal);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return new String(criptograma, Charset.defaultCharset());


}
```

And here is the output in Android Studio.
The output change to some readable characters to unreadable characters, never same length.

https://gyazo.com/574be22d0ef8f8b56f7fac805e09be33

The output should be: ThisIsMyAESkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to you not being accurate enough when specifying the algorithms you are using.

When providing the names of ciphers as strings e.g. "RSA" you should always be as specific as possible.  That means including the block mode and padding mode.

I don't know what padding mode you **expect** but be specific.  Try using `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` and `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`.

This will get your code working but it is far from actually secure.  Your ciphertext isn't authenticated and so can be modified, you are currently using ECB mode (e.g. no IV), and your application has no forward secrecy.  You've got a long way to go to make your code secure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i will try it and will report tomorrow. Im a junior so my knowledge in this area ( specially cryptography) is very very limited

Comment: @PedroPPL That's okay, everyone has to start somewhere!  If you intend on using this code in a production environment, however, you should probably consider scrapping it and just use TLS instead.

Comment: Hi, after some sleep ( I was really tired yesterday) and try what you told me its working like a charm. I also found that i wasnt calling the decrypt method on my code. However, after you told me that my code is far away for secure, im now exploring TLS and SSL. Thank you very much. Its true that StackOverflow is an awesome place.

Comment: @PedroPPL Happy to help!  I think you'll find that implementing TLS will be more time efficient and more secure for your project.  Good luck.